# TweenJS import error: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: webpack, three.js, nuxt.js, tween.js

I'm using NuxtJS with ThreeJS.

After I import TWEEN

```
import { TWEEN } from 'three/examples/jsm/libs/tween.module.min.js'
```

I get this error:

`Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'`

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of the day, I used standalone tweenjs package and it worked :)

https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js

Installed the package

```
npm i @tweenjs/tween.js@^18
```

Imported TWEEN

```
import * as TWEEN from '@tweenjs/tween.js'
```